# Usage of "benefit" in its verb form

Tags: meaning

I'm not a native English speaker. I'd like to ask a question about the usage of "benefit" in its verb form.

For example, 
"The device comprises A, B and C.  It benefits to be light and thin."

The usage of benefit like this...Is it sounds weird or wrong on it's grammar??

Because I think "benefit" in it's intransitive form means "derive sth good from", the usage like this may be grammatically wrong?

It would be appreciated if someone could answer this question <(_  _)>

Comment: You could say "it benefits from being light and thin", that sounds more natural to me. I can't really explain the grammatical rule however.

Answer (score -1):

> "The device comprises A, B and C. It benefits to be light and thin."

I would change to :

> The device is comprised of A, B, and C. This benefits the device, as it remains light and thin.

Comment: Or even just "This has the benefit of making it light and thin"